# How do I bypass the 1000 variable limit in Cplex

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, cplex, mixed-integer-programming, docplex

I've created a MILP model to test using the Docplex library in python but I get this error message :
CPLEX Error  1016: Community Edition. Problem size limits exceeded. Purchase at http://ibm.biz/error1016.

How do I bypass this limitation? Is there anyone with access to the unlimited version that can help me out?

Answer (score 2):

If you're a student or professor, you can find information about IBM's Academic Initiative program at http://ibm.biz/Bdzvqw.  This program gives you access to the unlimited version of our solvers.

Comment: Is there any other solution? I don't live in the US and my school is not in the IBM Academic intiative program.

Comment: This program is not limited to the US.  Just try to register. You may get a message saying that your school is not in the program yet. Please allow a few days for the review process to take place.  If, after one week, you still can't join, send a mail to cos-ai-support@wwpdl.vnet.ibm.com.

Comment: You can also have a look at the NEOS Server: https://neos-server.org/neos/solvers/index.html